# Regarding shared preferences in android

Tags: android

iam taking the data from user and storing in list and now i want to store the multiple data items of the list in shared preferences in android is it possible.

Answer (score 1):

SharedPreferences are not the ideal storage for data lists.

Even if you can do it, you would better consider using a database:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db